# communication between webserver and ms sql server using by websrvice

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight

Have a web application. After develop now want to install and have to change server address, server name, user name and password.
Already modify the application.Web Web.Config connection String just switch existing elements for the new one.

```
<connectionStrings> <add name="ConnstringName" connectionString="Data Source=SourceServerName;Initial Catalog=CName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=pwd" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" </connectionStrings>
```

And modify at the application the servicereferences.clientconfig file like this

```
<client>
<endpoint address="../Service1.svc" binding="customBinding"
bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_Service1" contract="ServiceReference1.Service1"
name="CustomBinding_Service1"/>
</client>
```

And after i testing my URL the application is running great but can't show me the data what receive from the database

Comment: You can't communicate with SQL server using web services. SQL server is a database.

Comment: After re-build the application is working, and i can communicate with database by using web service, because web service can send DML query and the server if u have grant execute it. Maybe didn't write whole application.